# Find text between @ and Space in a Message with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, text, parsing

I have text that is something like this:

sample text @dave more sample text

I need to just parse out and find "dave"

To clarify, I just have not used LEFT, RIGHT and LEN much so I am struggling on how to group those commands together to actually return that value. I can do it if just '@dave ' but not with all the other text around it. This is what I have currently:

```
MID(
[tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c, 
FIND("@", [tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c) + 1, 
FIND(" ", 
RIGHT([tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c, 
LEN([tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c) - 
FIND("@", [tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c)))
)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MID(
[tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c,
FIND("@", [tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c) + 1,
FIND(" ", RIGHT([tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c, LEN([tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c) - FIND("@", [tdc_tsw__Message__c].tdc_tsw__Message_Text_New__c))
)
)

try that let me know if its any good for what your looking for.

I'm no expert from your message I Gather you have a string like

' Hi troy @David cheers mate '

and you just want the 'David'

That formula should return what's in-between the '@' and next blank space

Comment: This looks to be exactly the same as what OP already has. As usual, pointing out the difference and explaining how it works is as important as the solution itself.

Comment: @DerekF Oh yeh haha! sorry didn't look at his original solution. If that's not what your after Troy I didn't really understand the question sorry mate. 
Cheers.